# Styled <hr> with border-radius appearing larger than defined height on non-FF browsers

Tags: html, firefox, css, cross-browser

I am experiencing x-browser issues with the styling of a `<hr>` within a `<span>`. On FF the line is 2px high as expected and as declared in the CSS. However, when I look at it on Safari, Chrome or IE9 the line looks much thicker. Infact, when the `<hr>` is inspected with Safari's Firebug equivalent it sees it as **4px**.

Is this an issue with the `border-radius` CSS attribute which is not apparent on Firefox? I want it to look like how I have built the markup and CSS and how it displays in Firefox, but i'm not sure what is wrong with the markup.

This is how it looks on Firefox:

[image: The HR on Firefox]

This is how it looks on Safari (and IE9/Chrome):

[image: The HR on Safari]

My markup:

```
<span id="course_divider"><hr></span>
```

My CSS:

```
#course_divider {
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 27px;
    width: 25px;
}

#course_divider hr {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    height: 2px;
}
```

Comment: hr {border:0;border-top:1px solid #555;margin:0;height:1px;}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `height` from

```
#course_divider hr {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    height: 2px;
}
```

you will get your solution :-)

demo  http://jsfiddle.net/kMhEv/2/

Answer (score 1):

It's simply an issue with your css in relation to the box model.

You have a height of 2px plus a border width of 1px.

So the box model is created with 1px at top/right/bottom/left.

So you 2px height plus 1px top+bottom for the border width = 4px height.

Remove the 2px height and it should be all good.

Your background color isn't required either.

```
#course_divider hr {
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
}
```